# Is "Suppose that _ is true; then _ is true" an incorrect usage of suppose? Is "presuppose" supposed to be used here?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verbs

I'm trying to understand what presuppose means, especially as opposed to "assume".

Comment: Some examples would help understand what you're asking about.

Comment: Broadly yes, that's incorrect. Specifically, the Question is not clear enough for a useful Answer.

Comment: While the use of *presuppose* is less common than *suppose* at the start of a sentence like this, both are grammatical and mean *essentially* the same thing (although there is a subtle difference). However, *neither* word gives meaning to what follows the semicolon—unless it's some fantasy world where somebody's thoughts can affect reality.

Answer (score 3):

You'd not start a sentence with 'presuppose'.

- Suppose that A is true. Then B follows.
- Suppose that x is an odd number. Then its square is odd too.
- Suppose that many people disobey the social distancing rules. Then a second wave will occur.

  You rarely use 'presuppose' other than when the contingent truth / state / goal / theory is also stated, and usually first.
- B being true/the case presupposes that A is true.
- Saying that we will eradicate the virus quickly presupposes that an effective and safe antiviral or vaccine will be discovered and tested quickly.
- The permanent presupposes human foresight. [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/presuppose)]
- Darwin’s theory doesn’t presuppose any special direction in evolution. [M-W]

'Presuppose that ...' is unidiomatic.

[edit: Thanks to Jason Bassford for pointing out the additional, rarer sense ('assume as an established fact to further build on'), usually taking a *that-clause* (possibly with 'that' deleted):

- the book presupposes **[that]** its readers will already know something about the subject (op cit)

but sometimes with a DO:

- The government cannot pass judgment upon or presuppose the illegitimacy of religious beliefs and practices. [op cit] [very formal; legal/political register] ]

*but this sense would be unidiomatic with OP's suggested syllogistic sentence*.

Comment: *"You only use 'presuppose' when the contingent truth is stated first. "* You have [**presupposed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presupposed) something that is incorrect.

Comment: All the **_examples_** given at M-W give the contingency first ('Onward' being non-sentient conforms to this; this is synecdoche for 'the setting of _Onward_'). [Google 3-grams for we pre/supposed that; I pre/supposed that](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+supposed+that%2Cwe+presupposed+that%2CI+supposed+that%2CI+presupposed+that&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwe%20supposed%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%20presupposed%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20supposed%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20presupposed%20that%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I presuppose you are now contradicting yourself. Many of the examples give no indication of any contingency at all before the use of *presuppose*. You can't have it both ways. The use of *presuppose* in the question is the same (aside from it being an imperative—where the subject is assumed) as its use in the Merriam-Webster examples.

Comment: And looking at [examples for 'I presupposed' in a Google search (with the filter -presupposing to eliminate declension lists, etc)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=qt-uXrmyJ8vVgQbLxq7oDw&q=%22I+presupposed%22+-presupposing+&oq=%22I+presupposed%22+-presupposing+&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1CwIliwImDzJ2gAcAB4AIABMogBkQGSAQEzmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi5r4bj_ZfpAhXLasAKHUujC_0Q4dUDCAw&uact=5)ff, apart from the odd archaic ones, there seem to be few that could be considered good examples of writing. And some dictionaries omit this sense.  But I'll change to 'It is uncommon ...'.